# Visual Studio does not load project because IIS Express is missing

Tags: visual-studio-2013, iis-express

I removed the IIS Express from the windows "programms installation" icon because I want to use ONLY the full IIS which is also activated from "programm installation".

Then I loaded my VS solution. The Web Api project got not loaded because its configured for IIS Express says the error message.

When I check the .csproj file I removed anything about the IIS Express.

But still with this content I get that error, why?

The only IIS related is this:

```
  <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
```

and its not about IIS express. Its the full IIS.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProductVersion>
    </ProductVersion>
    <SchemaVersion>2.0</SchemaVersion>
    <ProjectGuid>{A1E0B8DF-27CD-4551-900E-B73929E02942}</ProjectGuid>
    <ProjectTypeGuids>{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21};{fae04ec0-301f-11d3-bf4b-00c04f79efbc}</ProjectTypeGuids>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
    <RootNamespace>TGB.API</RootNamespace>
    <AssemblyName>TGB.API</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.6</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <UseGlobalApplicationHostFile />
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Autofac, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.3.5.2\lib\net40\Autofac.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Autofac.Integration.WebApi, Version=3.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=17863af14b0044da, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Autofac.WebApi2.3.4.0\lib\net45\Autofac.Integration.WebApi.dll</HintPath>
      <Private>True</Private>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="EntityFramework.SqlServer, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\EntityFramework.6.1.3\lib\net45\EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.2.2.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Hosting, Version=3.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Hosting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Newtonsoft.Json, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
      <HintPath>..\packages\Newtonsoft.Json.7.0.1\lib\net45\Newtonsoft.Json.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="NLog">
      <HintPath>..\packages\NLog.4.0.1\lib\net45\NLog.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Entity" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.ApplicationServices" />
    <Reference Include="System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Abstractions" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Routing" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Runtime.Serialization" />
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.Formatting, Version=__MvcPagesVersion__, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Net.Http.WebRequest">
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http, Version=__MvcPagesVersion__, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.WebHost, Version=__MvcPagesVersion__, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Owin.1.0\lib\net40\Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Facebook.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Google.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.Twitter.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.3.0.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.Owin.Security.MicrosoftAccount.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System.Web.Http.Owin">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin.5.2.3\lib\net45\System.Web.Http.Owin.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="App_Start\IdentityConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\JsonContentNegotiator.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\WebApiConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="App_Start\WebServicesConfig.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\GlobalExceptionHandler.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\GlobalExceptionLogger.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Infrastructure\ValidateModelStateFilter.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\AccountController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\HomeController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\SchoolclassCodesController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\PupilsController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\SchoolyearsController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Controllers\TestsController.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Global.asax.cs">
      <DependentUpon>Global.asax</DependentUpon>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="Models\AccountBindingModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\AccountViewModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Models\IdentityModels.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Providers\ApplicationOAuthProvider.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Results\ChallengeResult.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Startup.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="Client\Index.html" />
    <Content Include="Web.config" />
    <Content Include="Web.Debug.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
    <Content Include="Web.Release.config">
      <DependentUpon>Web.config</DependentUpon>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="App_Data\" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="Project_Readme.html" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TGB.DataAccess\TGB.DataAccess.csproj">
      <Project>{809d2f09-5c73-40e8-b032-5c9685d41056}</Project>
      <Name>TGB.DataAccess</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TGB.DataTransferObject\TGB.DataTransferObject.csproj">
      <Project>{56f38141-eee1-4a4a-baa4-ea6da81459b7}</Project>
      <Name>TGB.DataTransferObject</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TGB.Repository\TGB.Repository.csproj">
      <Project>{2de181ca-a13c-41ac-8b57-a6983c8aa298}</Project>
      <Name>TGB.Repository</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TGB.Service\TGB.Service.csproj">
      <Project>{20988323-fd06-418f-b6b5-195b9ae0f0f5}</Project>
      <Name>TGB.Service</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">10.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <VSToolsPath Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' == ''">$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)</VSToolsPath>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildBinPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="'$(VSToolsPath)' != ''" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v10.0\WebApplications\Microsoft.WebApplication.targets" Condition="false" />
  <Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <AspNetCompiler VirtualPath="temp" PhysicalPath="$(WebProjectOutputDir)" />
  </Target>
  <ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>53712</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
           <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
  <!-- To modify your build process, add your task inside one of the targets below and uncomment it.
       Other similar extension points exist, see Microsoft.Common.targets.
  <Target Name="BeforeBuild">
  </Target>
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
  </Target> -->
</Project>
```

Comment: I solved the problem by downloading IIS express 8 and installed this. Before I could not create any new web api project. Why is IIS express needed? stupid bug. After IIS express 8 installation I could load my project again. Hit F5 and then no IIS express 8 was in my tray icon because it was configured for IIS :-)

Comment: IIS Express is considered as part of VS.

Comment: In my VS2012 project Web settings I did not set the checkbox "Use IIS Express" as active but still the IIS express is starting when I hit F5, why is that? IIS and IIS Express surely cant both listen to port 80?